# How do you translate "My potions are too strong for you?"

Tags: word-comparison

It is really just the "are too strong for you" I am having trouble with. We haven't gone over how to say stuff like that in class yet. Would you use the superlative?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that nobody has answered this yet, so I decided to make an attempt myself (despite also being a student). Apologies for any mistakes, this is my first time answering a question on here.

I am not aware of any way to specifically say "are too strong", but I think the sentence below has a similar sense using *nimium*. I also used *potentiae* rather than something like *virtutes* in an attempt to make it sound more forceful.

> meus potiones nimium potentiae tibi habent - *My potions have too much strength for you*

Alternatively, you may be able to use phrases like "my potions will overpower you" or *aliquantae* (considerable [amount]) to express the level of strength in a different way.

Comment: This sounds like a nice translation, but I think *meus* should be *meae* to agree with *potiones*. I would have actually found *virtutes* inappropriate as it's about virtues and mental strength, whereas this is a matter of physical or chemical power.